# iPhone Web Appication deployment and distribution process

Tags: iphone

--I haven't develop any iPhone Web Application ever...so i am little bit confuse about that.

--I want to build a Web Application for iPhone which will be made using(CSS+JavaScript).

--I read some where that no approval is required for iPhone Web Application.

is it correct ?

--And if i have made my iPhone Web Application (using CSS+JavaScript)and uploaded at my server.

--and if i want to open it in UIWebView using iPhone SDK simply...

--is this Application is valid for iPhone Web Application portal https://adcweb.apple.com/iphone/index.php or not ?

--how can end users get the Application on their iPhone after submiting to the portal...

--can any one explain me the whole process of iPhone Web Application deployment and distribution process ?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'r building a web application, we talk about something, that does not need to be installed on the iPhone, because it runs inside the browser. So yes, you don't have to go through the approval process, it's just a website optimized for the iPhone. The submission you linked to in your question is to get *listed* at apple with your web application (I'm not sure  about the guidelines for that), it,s not a submission for the app store. You don't have to (and you should not) make use of the SDK by using UIWebView, because that would mean to build an *native* application which needs approval, has to be installed etc. If your goal is or can reached by building a web application, all the user needs is safari.

Answer (score 2):

iPhone (and others) have support for "stand alone" web apps. These are web apps that are designed to work offline. These applications are hosted on the web, but along with the application is a manifest file that describes all of the resources that the application will need. These resources are all downloaded to the device.

On the iPhone, to "install" one of these applications, you need to simply bookmark it. When you bookmark the app, the phone asks if you want an icon for it in the standard app area, vs just a bookmark in the browser.

Once bookmarked, the user can simply tap on the icon like any other application. This will launch safari for your application, and it starts using its local resource. There's no reason a standalone application that never touches the internet can't be written. The [Safari Reference Library](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/navigation/index.html) has a lot of information on this.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need approval for a web application.  The iPhone can view any web page through its browser (as long as there's no flash), so just implement your application as you normally would, but design for the smaller screen.  The submission form is just for listing in portals (I don't know which portals).

If you want to make a native iPhone application that talks to the server, then you need to sign up for a developer account and develop the application in Objective-C (with the help of `UIWebView`s, which are essentially embedded browser windows).  That will require approval.

Answer (score 0):

What about a web application that needs to be *installed*. By that I mean an application that consists of a web page (with embedded CSS and Javascript) that uses HTML5's localStorage to work offline. You still need to be able to access the page itself if you lost the connection, i.e. the page needs to be stored locally, because once you are offline, you can't access it from a server outside...